# Расчет местоположения планет в солнечной системе

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api, three.js

Создаю НАСАвский аналог 3D карты солнечной системы на THREE.js и Vue.
Столкнулся с проблемой определения текущего местоположения планет относительно солнца.

Сначала надеялся на интеграцию открытых API, 2 дня лазил по гуглу и ничего не нашел. Сервисы либо закрыты, либо им уже лет по 12 и особой ценности они не представляют.

Затем конечно же вышел на ресурс [HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi?s_type=1#top), но он предоставляет данные только по запросу через UI в виде html блока *(там нужно через телнет клиент запрашивать данные, чтобы в этом разобраться я убью кучу времени, а у меня осталось 2 дня до сдачи проекта)*.

Затем я нашел несколько библиотек: [astronomy.js](http://cosinekitty.com/solar_system.html), которая вцелом очень интересна, но я так и не понял как интегрировать ее с фреймом анимации планет, а также [js-horizons](https://github.com/zachfejes/js-horizons), но там у меня ломается конструктор объекта при иницализации запроса (ответа на ишью пока не получил на гите).

Может кто-нибудь знает подходящие API для подгрузки расположения планет в солнечной системе?

[image: прототип]

Comment: Галилей и его друзья вроде создали API лет 400 назад, оно кстати в отрытом доступе и без лицензии. Нужео только текущее время. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_mechanics

Comment: astronomy.js H - Heliocentric. Hx, Hy, Hz почему эти координаты не подошли?

Comment: @moxolim не выходит их подтянуть при онлоаде страницы, выдает cors reject

Comment: получение console.log(Astronomy.Body[1].EclipticCartesianCoordinates(Astronomy.DayValue(new Date())));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Спасибо @moxolim за отличную подсказку.*

**Решение с расчетом на стороне пользователя:** 
[Берем исходник astronomy.js](http://cosinekitty.com/astronomy.js) 
[Или рефактор под es9 (иcключает все ошибки)](https://github.com/letUser/Solar_System_Map/blob/master/src/components/calculations/astronomy.js)

Создаем у себя файл astronomy.js и копируем код. 
*Обратите внимание, что **исходнику** нужно будет добавить:

```
export {
    Astronomy
};
```

Далее импортим куда нужно:

```
import { Astronomy } from "./astronomy.js";
```

Получаем объект с XYZ координатами:

```
console.log(Astronomy.Body[1].EclipticCartesianCoordinates(Astronomy.DayValue(new Date())))
//[1] - это меркурий
```

Кодировка небесных тел:

```
[1] //Меркурий
[2] //Венера
[3] //Земля
[4] //Луна
[5] //Марс
[6] //Церера
[7] //Палада
[8] //Юнона
[9] //Веста
[10] //Ида
[11] //Гаспра
[12] //9P/T1
[13] //19P/B
[14] //67P/C-G
[15] //81P/W2
[16] //Юпитер
[17] //Сатурн
[18] //Уран
[19] //Нептун
[20] //Плутон
```